# How to automatically save downloaded file from a browser without going through the confirmation browser dialog in jsf?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, browser, richfaces, webbrowser-control

I have a `jsf` unit test that test if a download file is successful, but the problem is that when the download button was clicked i am blocked because I cannot refer my code to the download dialog from browser that I'm using. I cannot click the `OK` button from my code, I've tried the `jQuery` code a while ago but the enter key does not trigger the `OK` button of the dialog.

Is there a way to refer to the download dialog of the browser, i want to do it in the bean.
Thanks.